# Twilio message body - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twilio

I am having a small problem with Twilio. I am trying to send an SMS with some
data on the user database table so that i can verify who they are.

[Sending the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms) from the user controller .

```
  def verifymobile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
     message_to_send  = @user.phoneverify

    # Instantiate a Twilio client
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.account.sms.messages.create(
        from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
        to: @user.cellphone,
        body: "Thanks for signing up with Afrocoin. To verify your account, 
             Please use CODE #{message_to_send}"
    )

    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
```

I am having a problem getting the data to go with the message body (@user.phoneverify). Can you please advise

Comment: Are you sure there is a valid value for `@user` and `@user.phoneverify` ?

Comment: Just a couple of things come to mind after looking at this: 1) Too many characters. 2) `message_to_send` is nil. 3) Set the string to a variable. Not saying any of those are correct. Just things to consider.

Comment: @Daedalus you are right. There was nothing there. Why don't you add an answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is a valid value for @user and @user.phoneverify ?